# Sending two text files content as body in a mail

Tags: email, vbscript

I have two text files:

```
c:\file1.txt
c:\file2.txt
```

I want to mail content of both files as a body in a single email using VBScript.
I am trying with below code but its not working.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8
Const FileToBeUsed = "c:\file1.txt"
Const FileToBeUsed = "c:\file2.txt"
Dim objCDO1
Dim fso, f
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(FileToBeUsed, ForReading)
Set objCDO1 = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objCDO1.Textbody = f.ReadAll
f.Close
objCDO1.TO ="sunny@abc.com"
objCDO1.From = "dontreply@abc.com (CCP Stored Procedure Message)"
objCDO1.Subject = "CCP Stored Procedure"
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration   /sendusing") = 2 
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtpb.intra.abc.com"
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration /smtpserverport") = 25 
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Update     
objCDO1.Send
Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

please help me out.

**EDIT1**

When I modified above code as:

```
Const FileToBeUsed = "c:\file1.txt"
Const FileToBeUsed = "c:\file2.txt"
--------------------------
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(FileToBeUsed1, ForReading) + fso.OpenTextFile(FileToBeUsed2, ForReading)
-----------------------------

objCDO1.Textbody = fso.OpenTextFile(FileToBeUsed1, ForReading).ReadAll + fso.OpenTextFile(FileToBeUsed2, ForReading).ReadAll
```

Its throwing runtime Error at line 9:

**Object doesn't support this property or Method.**

**EDIT2**

I have a text file as:

**output.txt:**

```
OPERATING SYSTEM       SERVER1    SERVER2
Windows                  1.36       4.42
Linux                    2.78       5.76
MacOS                    3.45       6.39
Ubuntu                   4.12       0.00
Android                  0.00       3.46
FreePhysicalMemory      30.12      31.65
TotalVisibleMemorySize  48.00      48.00
```

I want to send content of Output.txt in a email as a body sothat its format (alignment) doesn't get changed (like an HTMIL table format):

How i can attach Output.txt file's content in form of HTML table to the email Body..?

**EDIT3**

Now i have created below code:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8
Dim objEmail, i
Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objEmail.Textbody = myTextBody
objEmail.HTMLBody = myHTMLBody
If IsArray( myAttachment ) Then
For i = 0 To UBound( "c:\output.txt" )
.AddAttachment Replace( "c:\output.txt" ( i ), "" ),"",""
 Next
ElseIf myAttachment <> "" Then
.AddAttachment Replace( "c:\output.txt", ""),"",""
End If
objEmail.TO ="sunny@abc.com"
objEmail.From = "dontreply@abc.com (CCP Stored Procedure Message)"
objEmail.Subject = "CCP Stored Procedure"
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration    /sendusing") = 2 
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtpb.intra.abc.com"
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration /smtpserverport") = 25 
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update     
objEmail.Send
Set objEmail = Nothing
```

Mail sent but in mail body getting nothing..what is error above ?

Comment: What is the output of `WScript.Echo TypeName(fso)`?

Comment: Hi Ansgar..when i removed the **set f** functionality..above code is working perfectly..thanks for your response..! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a constant

```
Const FileToBeUsed = "c:\file1.txt"
```

How can it change to another value ?

```
Const FileToBeUsed = "c:\file2.txt"
```

Try

```
Const FileToBeUsed1 = "c:\file1.txt"
Const FileToBeUsed2 = "c:\file2.txt"
....
objCDO1.Textbody = fso.OpenTextFile(FileToBeUsed1, ForReading).ReadAll + fso.OpenTextFile(FileToBeUsed2, ForReading).ReadAll
```

EDIT (HTMLBody)

```
Dim hb
    hb = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\TheFileWithColumnsInIt.txt",ForReadin).ReadAll
    hb = "<html><body><code>" + hb + "</code></body></html>"

objCD01.HTMLBody = hb
```

And in prevision of problems (some versions of CDO have documented problems), please read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527263%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Pls see **EDIT1** in question.

Comment: You don't need to set f= ... The open and read of the file is done in place when asigned to the Textbody property.

Comment: @MC..i am not able to send a excel file's content using above code. In received mail only some jumbled symbols are coming.why its happening ?

Comment: TextBody ONLY contains text. After setting TextBody you need to attach the excell file to the message `objCD01.AddAttachment "C:\WhatEver\YourFile.xls"`

Comment: but i think that will send excel file as an attachment not its content as a body..if i am not mistaken..:)

Comment: Correct. But you can not send excel object in text field. Maybe you could investigate [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa494089%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) to get more options, but attachments seems the most practical solution.

Comment: @MC..Pls see **EDIT2** in question..:)

Comment: Follow link in previous comment. Format your file into html and use the HTMLBody property.